# Google Api - Get Users Email id

Tags: google-api

I am using Google API - PHP client to connect to Google Analytics API. Is there any way i can get the email Address of the User while Authenticating the user and Granting the permissions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Google Management API for Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference). When you make the authenticated call to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly, you will receive back (among other things) a username which is defined as "Email address of the authenticated user".